# .class error during declaring/initializing variables?

Tags: java

I'm in the process of learning java. Today, my task was to find the errors in some code. I'm in the process of working on it, but I have no idea why the following error occurs. In the sample code, it gives me a ".class expected" on the line "int momsAge= 42; dadsAge= 43;" specifically, it puts an error line right infront of momsAge.

```
// A class that computes the sample statistics of the ages of
// family members.
public class FamilyStats
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
/*
math equations obtained from: */
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SampleVariance.html

// define some ages

int momsAge= 42; dadsAge= 43;
int myAge= 22, sistersAge= 16;
int dogsAge= 6;

// get the mean

double ageSum = (momsAge + dadsAge + myAge + sistersAge + DogsAge);
double average = ageSum / 5

/ calculate the sample variance
double variance= 0.0;
variance += (momsAge - average)*(momsAge - average);
variance += (dadsAge - average)(dadsAge - average);
variance += (myAge - average)*(myAge - average);
variance += (sistersAge - average)*(sistersAge - average);
variance += (dogsAge - average)*(dogsAge - average);
variance = variance / 4;

// get the std. dev
double standardDev= Math.sqrt(variance);
// output the results
System.out.println("The sample age mean is: " + average);
System.out.println("The sample age variance is: " + variance);
System.out.println("The sample age standard deviation is: " + standardDev);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int momsAge= 42; dadsAge= 43;
```

should be

```
int momsAge= 42, dadsAge= 43;
```

The `;` serves as the end of the statement, thus essentially making your next statement

`dadsAge = 43;`

Obviously this is wrong because a class is expected. Using the `,` allows you to chain those assignments.

Also:

`http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SampleVariance.html`

isn't commented (at least the `http:` part isn't).

Comment: or insert another `int` after the semicolon -> `int momsAge= 42; int dadsAge= 43;`

Comment: So, I went back and changed that (thanks), but it is still giving me a .class expected error, in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct code with the inline corrections that I made:

```
// A class that computes the sample statistics of the ages of
// family members.
public class FamilyStats {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
         math equations obtained from: 
         http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SampleVariance.html
         */ 
       //^--Included the url into the comments
// define some ages
        int momsAge = 42, dadsAge = 43;
                      //^--Changed ; to ,
        int myAge = 22, sistersAge = 16;
        int dogsAge = 6;

// get the mean

        double ageSum = (momsAge + dadsAge + myAge + sistersAge + dogsAge);
        double average = ageSum / 5;
        // calculate the sample variance
       //^--Added the second / to mark the line as a comment
        double variance = 0.0;
        variance += (momsAge - average) * (momsAge - average);
        variance += (dadsAge - average) * (dadsAge - average);
        variance += (myAge - average) * (myAge - average);
                                    //^--Added missing * symbol
        variance += (sistersAge - average) * (sistersAge - average);
        variance += (dogsAge - average) * (dogsAge - average);
        variance = variance / 4;

// get the std. dev
        double standardDev = Math.sqrt(variance);
// output the results
        System.out.println("The sample age mean is: " + average);
        System.out.println("The sample age variance is: " + variance);
        System.out.println("The sample age standard deviation is: " + standardDev);
    }
}
```